# Open image file nullpointer exception

Tags: java, image, file, nullpointerexception

I have to change the icon of a label every 2 seconds. I have 3 pictures in src folder. To change them i use a thread. The code i wrote:

```
    private Thread t;
    private int indexIcon;
    public ImageIcon[] icons = {new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("orange.jpg")),   
    new     
    ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("cosmote.jpg")), new 
    ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("vodafone.jpg"))};
    public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                return;
            }
            indexIcon++;
            if (indexIcon > 2) {
                indexIcon = 0;
            }
            jLabel8.setIcon(icons[indexIcon]);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CarteDeTelefonGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the class constructor:

```
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
```

It works fine, but the problem is that when i run the program on a different computer it doesn't read the images, i get a nullpointer exception. 
How could i solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use a Thread. Updates to Swing components should be done on the EDT. Instead you should be using a Swing Timer.

Comment: On which line do you get the NPE?

Comment: I get the NPE on the third line.

Comment: You probably aren't including the images correctly in your jar.  Make sure you are doing that properly and this error will go away.

Comment: The images are included in the src folder in the jar.